# How can I add new Java class for mapping with data base?

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'm currently working in a company where there is no documentation of the main application, so I must use try and failure techniques in each change I must make.

This application is developed on JSF 1.2 with JDK 6 and some auxiliary tools like RichFaces and Hibernate, connected to the database engine MS SQL Server. At the moment, I must add a new selector that must feed from the database, but whenever I execute the following code line:

```
return this.entityManager.createQuery("select d from DiagnosticoPrueba d").getResultList();
```

It shows the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DiagnosticoPrueba  is not mapped [select d from DiagnosticoPrueba d]
```

The process I used to add the new selector was the following:

1. I created the `DIAGNOSTICO` table and inserted the respective data. To corroborate this information, I'll show you the result from the following sentences.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM DIAGNOSTICO;
   ```

[image]

```
EXEC sp_columns DIAGNOSTICO;
```

[image]

2. I created the JavaDiagnosticoPrueba class that will map the DIAGNOSTICO table

   ```
   package *.entidades;

   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;

   @Entity (name = "DiagnosticoPrueba")
   @Table(name = "DIAGNOSTICO")
   public class DiagnosticoPrueba implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private int id;
   private String nombre;

   public DiagnosticoPrueba() {
   }

   public DiagnosticoPrueba(int id, String nombre) {
       this.id = id;
       this.nombre = nombre;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 200)
   public String getNombre() {
       return nombre;
   }

   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
       this.nombre = nombre;
   }
   }
   ```

The file `hibernate.cfg.xml` can't be found in the application, but there is the file `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MY_ENTERPRISE" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myEnterpriseDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="MY_ENTERPRISE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="SCHEMA_MY_ENTERPRISE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I consider the error is due to not having the entity `DiagnosticoPrueba` in the configuration files from the application, and I think the key to the solution is at `myEnterpriseDataSource`.

What would you recommend me to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the classes in your persistence.xml

Set outside properties section.

```
<class>com.mycompany.entities.DiagnosticoPrueba</class>
```